# Create a function at runtime that has a specific number of arguments in python

Tags: python, functional-programming

Is it possible to create a function with a fixed number of arguments at runtime?

I need to create a function that composes two functions, so that I get
`f_new(x,a,b,c,d,e) = f_1(x,a,b) + f_2(x,c,d,e)` for two arbitrary functions `f_1` and `f_2`.
Using an approach like

```
from inspect import signature
def combine(f_1,f_2):
    arg_len_1 = len(signature(f_1).parameters) - 1
    arg_len_2 = len(signature(f_2).parameters) - 1
    def combined(x,*args):
        return f_1(x,args[:arg_len_1]) + f_2(x,args[arg_len_1:arg_len_2])
    return combined
```

does not work for me, as  you can't apply it twice because the number of arguments gets lost in the process.

Is there any way to achieve this in python **without** using `eval()` or is that the only option?

Comment: I think `eval()`/`exec()`/`compile()` would be the only way of making a function that would report the right number of parameters via `signature()`.  Perhaps you could store the intended number of parameters in an attribute such as `f_1.my_argcount`, and write a replacement for `signature()` that uses that attribute if present, or calls the original `signature()` otherwise.